# Dart: Memory leak in Function's lexical closure that captures other objects

Tags: flutter, dart

I come to Dart from Swift, and one thing that I'm wondering is if a Function variable can cause memory leaks if it captures some other object.

In Swift, this can be prevented by declaring these objects weak, for example:

```swift
class A {
    var a = "Hello World"
    var closure: () -> Void {
        { [weak self] in 
            if self == nil {
                print("Nil")
            }
            print(self?.a ?? "")
        }
    }
}

A().closure() // Output: Nil
```

The equivalent of this in Dart is:

```dart
class A {
  String a = "Hello World";
  void Function() get function {
    return () {
      print(a);
    };
  }
}

void main() {
  A().function(); // Output: Hello World
}
```

Wouldn't this potentially create memory leaks if the function is kept alive while the objects are not being used anymore, these objects could be anything? If so then do you guys know the proper way to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Dart’s runtime includes a garbage collector. its function is to deallocating memory.

Comment: I mean how does the collector deallocate the function in the case where some other object is holding a reference to function? like other object(in use) -> function -> the captured object (no longer in use)